# entityform submit handler with preview

Tags: 7, forms, entities

I have a simple [Entity Form](https://drupal.org/project/entityform) and have added a custom submit handler:

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'] = array('custom_submit','entityform_edit_form_submit');
```

That works very well. The problem is when I enable form preview before submission. My `custom_submit` function runs before preview is generated and not after it was confirmed.

How do I get it to run after form has been confirmed in preview?

```
$form['#submit']  = array(
    'custom_submit',
    'entityform_edit_form_submit'
);
```

does not work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is what I found entityform module does. If preview is enabled it set `$form['review']`. All of my forms will have that preview set so what I did is simply:

```
//check if form is in preview mode and if it is then it adds my custom handler.
if(isset($form['review'])) { 
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] ='custom_submit'
}
```

Comment: you might want to make sure that `custom_submit` runs before default one. (shift array)

Answer (score 0):

You should add your submit handler to the end of the array like so:

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'custom_submit';
```

Comment: `custom_submit` still runs in preview with above code..

Comment: please provide the form config for your preview button.

Comment: its a default entityform button. no changes have been made there:
`
          [submit] => Array
                (
                    [#type] => submit
                    [#value] => Submit
                    [#entityform_draft] => 0
                    [#submit] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => entityform_edit_form_submit
                            [1] => ramp_randomise
                        )

                    [#disabled] => 
                    [#entityform_after_review] => 
                    [#executes_submit_callback] => 1
                )`